# Calculate MRR(Monthly Recurring Revenue) using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate MRR(Monthly Recurring Revenue) in SQL Server. I have a table with columns:

- transactionTime - datetime
- userId  - varchar
- paymentId  - int
- amount  - decimal

I guess that MRR is just the sum of amount grouped by month.

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, transactionTime), 0) month, 
    SUM(amount) AS mrr
FROM 
    payments
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, transactionTime), 0)
```

Is it correct way to calculate MRR?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what YOU mean by "MRR".

Answer (score 1):

MRR is usually defined as the amount which is contracted to recur every month, so calculating it is usually not necessary.

If you are just after a query that sums up the amount per month, you are close.

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(Year, transactionTime) AS YEAR,
    DATEPART(Month, transactionTime) AS MONTH, 
    SUM(amount) AS MRR, 
    SUM(amount) / COUNT(DISTINCT userId) AS arpu
FROM 
    payments
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(Year, transactionTime),
    DATEPART(Month, transactionTime)
```

If adding per user

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(Year, transactionTime) AS YEAR,
    DATEPART(Month, transactionTime) AS MONTH,
    userId AS USER_ID,
    SUM(amount) AS MRR
FROM 
    payments
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(Year, transactionTime),
    DATEPART(Month, transactionTime),
    userId
```

Comment: Thanks. I have doubts, because there are many kinds of MRR(New MRR, Expansion MRR and so on). But i need to calc simple MRR (i guess it just the sum of amount by month).